# Read a text file from s3 Node.js - Missing some part at the beginning

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm new to AWS and Node.js.
I wrote a 224x224x3 array into a text file and saved it in a s3 bucket. I need to read that text file in another lambda function written in Node.js and assign that array to a variable.
But it seems like sometimes some part of the array has missed at the beginning.

Below is the Python code I used to store the array into a text file.
Please note that the returnArr is a 224x224x3 list.

```
with open("/tmp/out.txt", "w") as file:
     file.write(str(returnArr))
     file.close()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
BUCKET = "tempimagebucket1"
s3.Bucket(BUCKET).upload_file("/tmp/out.txt", "out.txt")
```

Below is the Node.js code I used to read the array stored in the text file.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
exports.handler = async (event, ctx, callback) => {
     var params1 = {Bucket: 'tempimagebucket1', Key: 'out.txt'};
     await s3.getObject(params1 , function (err, data1) {
       if (err) {
          console.log(err);
       } else {
          console.log("array : ",data1.Body.toString()); //Line 1
          img = data1.Body.toString();
       }
    }).promise(); 
}
```

Issue - Sometimes Line 1 gives an incomplete array (Some part of the array has missed at the beginning).
Sometimes it gives the complete array successfully.

Please note that the array stored in the text file is always complete. So the issue should be in the Node.js Lambda function.

Some of the incomplete outputs are below (Line 1 output).
Read array is different at different times.
array : 57, 27], [92, 43, 13], [89, 41, 11], [90, 43, 14], [89, 44, 18], [79, 37, 15], [59, 26, 8], [48, 27, 11], [111, 66, 33], [118, 77, 40] ...

array : 72], [164, 120, 73], [153, 105, 61], [140, 89, 44], [142, 91, 43], [156, 107, 60], [156, 108, 62], [164, 116, 69], [171, 123, 77], [161, 112, 67], [160, 111, 67] ...

But it should be something like below - Output should be a complete 3d array
array :  [[[107, 90, 72], [96, 79, 62], [86, 69, 52], [59, 43, 28], [43, 26, 15], [50, 32, 20], [58, 38, 21], [77, 46, 25], [81, 50, 22], [96, 65, 39]...

I can't figure out the reason for that.
Can someone please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: `/tmp/out.txt` is a regular text file, and is correctly written to s3?

Comment: @Marcin I created the /tmp/out.txt file and wrote the array using the Python code given above. And yes, the array is correctly written to s3. The issue is in reading it from Node.js lambda function.

Comment: You are using a callback and a promise? I am not a Javascript developer, but that looks wrong. Use either one or the other. For example: `const data = await s3.getObject(params1).promise();`

Comment: The JS code is fine. I run it with some text data. It works as expected. What is your `returnArr`?

Comment: @Marcin returnArr is a 224x224x3 list. Elements are R, G, B pixel values of an image. In the Python lambda function, I apply some filters to a 224x224 size RGB image and after applying the filters I convert the image array into a list using returnArr = imageArray.tolist(). Then I write that 224x224x3 array into the text file and save it in a s3bucket. Is this because the size of the array is too large?

Comment: @Marcin A sample text file is available at the following link. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zM9A4ANIn-_VkEre16F7QKhE2VidsqDI?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Your function and test file **are correct**. However, I see what you mean by missing beginning:

[image]

This is just console trimming the output. You can press **Load more** and you will see full text:

[image]

Comment: No, my outputs are something like follows (Some part has missed at the beginning - only sometimes) 2021-07-27T05:55:37.376Z e627dbcb-6550-4f21-ab78-74959c90d75c INFO array :  , [103, 91, 72], [84, 74, 62], [94, 83, 68], [106, 92, 76], [125, 111, 93], [141, 125, 105], [142, 125, 103], [126, 107, 81], [111, 90, 63], [107, 84, 56], [121, 96, 64], [138, 110, 76], [152, 124, 86], [159, 132, 91], [155, 126, 82], [148, 116, 70], [152, 121, 78], [152, 121, 79] ...

Comment: @MalieshaKalutota Your code definitly works and the out.txt is fine. Are you sure that what you provided in your question  is the actual code that you use?

Comment: My Python code and the node.js code are a bit long. I included only the related code blocks in the question. Shall I upload the 2 whole codes into previous Google Drive link for you? Is that okay? Thanks

Comment: I've uploaded two Python and node.js code in the link below (crop_neutralization.py and index.js) https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zM9A4ANIn-_VkEre16F7QKhE2VidsqDI?usp=sharing Could you kindly take a look? Thanks in advance